# Magento Product Placeholder Image

Tags: magento

I have product placeholder images set in the backend at System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders

I can half-successfully access a product placeholder image programmatically in one of my views using the following code:

```
$this->getSkinUrl($this->helper('catalog/image')->init(
Mage::getModel('catalog/product'), 'small_image'));
```

My issue is that the above returns:

```
http://x.dev/skin/frontend/base/default/http://x.dev/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/placeholder/default/logo_4.jpg*
```

It seems like getSkinUrl does what it says and adds the skin path to the string, this is my **real issue**, to fix the issue I thought I would just remove getSkinUrl:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init(
Mage::getModel('catalog/product'), 'small_image');
```

But the above code throws:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
```

Can anyone see a problem with this, I seem to be doing less and it seems to be getting stuck in a loop.

Alternatively does anybody know an alternative method? I am really stuck and I really don't want to hard code it.

Thanks

Comment: It seems odd to me that you specify an empty product model instead of a loaded product. What if you use `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init(
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<some_id>), 'small_image');` where <some_id> is a product id?

Comment: @Lucasmus Unfortunately that gives exactly the same issue. Interestingly I var_dumped Mage::getModel('catalog/product') with and without an productId and without had no mention of image whilst with productId gave an image location but it was of the product not of the placeholder. In an extremely hacky way if I specify an none existing Id I get the correct place holder.   `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1247901)->getSmallImageUrl(200,200));`  Thanks for your idea, got my mind working. Any other ideas for not such a hacky way.

Comment: I ended up using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getSmallImageUrl(200,200))`, bit hacky but does the trick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many thanks to @Lucasmus for setting me on the right track.

I ended up solving this in a bit of a hacky way, but it works.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getSmallImageUrl(200,200);
```

That will get you the product placeholder image set in System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders

**Edit**

As @Tyler V pointed out this is a depreciated method, if you don't wish to use it you can use the same logic of the method it is a bit more verbose:

```
    (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product'),
        'small_image'
    )->resize(200, 200);
```

Comment: This method has been deprecated since 1.1.5